# How do I take a string, convert it to an array, and then call specific characters from that array to create a new string?

Tags: rust

Now that I'm typing it, this seems like a very convoluted process that could definitely be solved easier. Ignoring that for the moment, I'm trying to take a string (from user input), separate the characters into an array, then call individual characters to make a new string. The issue I'm running into is that the "join" function doesn't like working with the "Vec" function (not sure if function is the right term, sorry). Here is my code so far:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
  println!("Enter P1:");
  
  let mut mono = String::new();

  io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut mono)
    .expect("Failed to read line");
  
  let mono: Vec<char> = mono.chars().collect();
  let x = [mono[0],mono[1]].join("");
  println!("Square 1: {x}");
}
```

I'm very new to Rust, so any suggestions are extremely helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just slice the original string `str[a..b].to_string()`.

If you need to work with char arrays, there's `String::from_iter` and collecting into a `String`. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=271c8264a2eaf380444da994b4d893f8):

```rust
fn main() {
    let string = "My String".to_string();
    let substr1 = string[0..3].to_string();
    let substr2 = string[3..].to_string();
    println!("substr1 = {}", substr1);
    println!("substr2 = {}", substr2);
    
    let chars: Vec<_> = string.chars().collect();
    
    let collected_substr1: String = chars.iter().take(2).collect();
    let collected_substr2: String = chars.iter().skip(3).collect();
    println!("collected_substr1 = {}", collected_substr1);
    println!("collected_substr2 = {}", collected_substr2);
    
    let from_iter_substr1 = String::from_iter([chars[0], chars[1]].iter());
    let from_iter_substr2 = String::from_iter(chars.iter().skip(3));
    println!("from_iter_substr1 = {}", from_iter_substr1);
    println!("from_iter_substr2 = {}", from_iter_substr2);
    
}
```

Comment: 'String::from_iter' was exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Vec` is a type, FYI.

`join` only works on string slices (`&str`), not `char`s. Assuming you are just trying to join two characters without a separator, you can do

```rust
let x: String = mono.chars().take(2).collect();
```

Comment: Just to mock-up what I'm trying to do: String: "AABB", Array ["A","A","B","B"], String: "AB" I only have two characters in my actual code just for simplicity while I'm trying it out

Comment: @CostonPritchett The code in your example would produce `"AA"`, not `"AB"`. Can you explain with more examples? It's unclear if you want to get the unique set of characters, or the middle two characters, or exclude the first and last characters.

Comment: Definitely my bad on that on. My example code was just combining two characters from the array. My end goal is to be able to take two specific characters from an array and combine them into a string. String "ABCD" Array ["A","B","C","D"] String "BC", for example.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is only to extract a substring from the input it can be done much simpler

```rs
use std::io;

fn main() {
  println!("Enter P1:");
  
  let mut mono = String::new();

  io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut mono)
    .expect("Failed to read line");
  
  let x = &mono[..2].to_string(); // get rhe slice you need and create a new string from it

  println!("Square 1: {x}");
}
```

Edit

As pointed out in comments, note that in a real life use case you should check the length of your string before slicing in it with arbitrary indexes... this example could easily crash at runtime.

Comment: Note this does not work if either of the first two characters does not fit within a single byte, and will panic at runtime in that case.

Comment: @PitaJ yes I guess this is a little too simplistic... I edited my suggestion.